# Updating already created unique index PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a unique index name `account_id_status_idx` already created in PostgreSQL.

```
create unique index account_id_status_idx on customer (account_id, status);
```

I updated the table with a new column named `shop_id`. now account_id, status and shop_id also need to be unique.

```
create unique index account_id_status_shop_id_idx on customer (account_id, status, shop_id);
```

Now `account_id` to be optional. new rows violate the 1st index since null values.
Ex: (account_id=0, status=active,shop_id=1), (account_id=0, status=active,shop_id=2). account_id default should be 0.

So I need to update the 1st index as expected

```
 alter index account_id_status_idx (account_id, status) where account_id!=0;
```

So. is it possible to update the index using `ALTER` without drop and re-create in PostgreSQL?

Comment: You need to drop the existing index and create a new one.

Comment: You are changing the scope of the index. I would think it needs to be re-created.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing "magic" IDs if you don't have a value. `account_id` should be `NULL` not `0`. The `0` might even indicate a missing foreign key between customer and account or do you really have a account with `ID=0`?